# Plain C: Why is this scanf code not working?

Tags: c

Is merging printing and scanning possible in C? I trying to run this code and it is not asking for any input, but rather just putting in some garbage value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("Enter first number: %d", &a );

    scanf ("Enter the second number: %d", &b);
    scanf("Enter the third number: %d", &c);

    printf("%d == %d is %d \n", a, b, a == b);
    printf("%d == %d is %d \n", a, c, a == c);

    printf("%d > %d is %d \n", a, b, a > b);
    printf("%d > %d is %d \n", a, c, a > c);

    printf("%d < %d is %d \n", a, b, a < b);
    printf("%d < %d is %d \n", a, c, a < c);

    printf("%d != %d is %d \n", a, b, a != b);
    printf("%d != %d is %d \n", a, c, a != c);

    printf("%d >= %d is %d \n", a, b, a >= b);
    printf("%d >= %d is %d \n", a, c, a >= c);

    printf("%d <= %d is %d \n", a, b, a <= b);
    printf("%d <= %d is %d \n", a, c, a <= c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Text in the scanf format string requires the input to match that text. The man page for scanf explains: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: The only way to merge printing and scanning in C is to write a function that calls `printf`, and then calls `scanf`. And if you want the function call to look exactly as you've written, you'll need to split the prompt string at the space after the colon. Then pass the first portion to `printf` and the second portion to `scanf`.

Answer (score 5):

The string (format string) you pass to `scanf` is **not** something that will be printed. It is the **input** that it looks for.

So when you do:

```
scanf("Enter first number: %d", &a );
```

it looks for input like "Enter first number: 42" If you just type a number like "42" `scanf` will not match anything so no value will be assigned to `a`.

You probably want:

```
printf("Enter first number: ");
if (scanf("%d", &a ) != 1) 
{
    // error - the input did not match an int
    exit(1);
}
// now a contains the scanned number
printf("The scanned value is %d\n", a);
```